# Is "*this = {}" valid inside a member function for reset in CPP

Tags: c++, performance, coding-style, undefined-behavior

Recently, I was unhappy to find that I often ended up reproducing the constructor's behavior every time I had to create a "reset" function for an object.

Example:

```
class Foo
{
    int i;
public:
    Foo() : i(42) {};
    void reset() {
        i = 42;
    }
};
```

To solve this problem, I came up with the idea of calling the constructor directly in the reset function to ensure that the behavior is the same.

Modified example:

```
class Foo
{
    int i;
public:
    Foo() : i(42) {};
    void reset() {
        *this = {};
    }
};
```

This worked well, but a couple of questions came to mind that I haven't found the answer to yet:

- Is it valid to do this? Is this UB somehow ?
- Given that it involves creating and copying an object, could it be less efficient to do it this way (without optimization)?
- Would you consider this a good practice to avoid duplication? Or is there another, more consensual way of proceeding?

Thanks

Comment: Adapt the builder pattern?

Comment: This is perfectly fine. In this simple case As-if rule takes over and there should not be any difference in permanence. For more complex types there can be a significant difference.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/GhsTb1oqv

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it, though if this is the only thing the function does, I'd rather not have function called `reset` and just call `val = {};` to reset it.

Comment: As long as your class is default constructible, there is no reason to have a `reset` member function.  You can just do `my_variable = {};` in your source code instead of `my_variable.reset();`

Comment: Note that if you find yourself creating such a “reset” function very often, that’s a code smell. With a proper class design it should be rarely, if ever, necessary to reset a class instance (except to implement move construction, because … C++ lacks destructive move).

Comment: @NathanOliver-IsonStrike & ALX23z  I agree with you, but I think it would be more explicit to include it in a "reset" function. And if later the way of resetting the object changes, the change will be concentrated in one place.

Comment: @sweenish could you be more specific?

Comment: @MarekR I'm intrigued at the link. What don't I know that allows that code to compile without a `main()`?

Comment: @sweenish Compiling C++ code without a `main` function has never been a problem. If it were, you couldn’t have separate compilation units. But if you try *linking* the code you’ll get an “undefined reference” error.

Comment: @KonradRudolph That doesn't help me in this particular instance. I see no `-c` being passed. I'm not a beginner. But given the compile command, I expected to see an error. Because it looks like it *should* be attempting to link.

Comment: @sweenish Godbolt adds the `-c` flag (along with other flags, depending on the options chosen in the UI).

Comment: @KonradRudolph That's helpful. No mystery, just hidden flags.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's fine.

What you are doing is using the implicitly defined operator= (given for free by the compiler since you did not define one yourself).

The operator= expects a reference to another Foo object:

```
operator=(const Foo&)
```

or

```
operator=(Foo&&)
```

You are giving it an empty [list initializing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) which is perfectly defined for the Foo you created, as a class constructor that is not marked as explicit is a definition for a possible implicit conversion from the list of arguments given to a class constructed by the matching constructor.

In your case, since you are giving an empty list, you simply ask for implicit conversion to Foo{}, meaning that you wish for this code:

```
*this = Foo{};
```

which means to assign my object with the default constructed Foo, which is born with i=42.

The default operator= would simply bitwise-copy the object given as an argument into the executing object (*this).

So after this, you get that this->i = 42.

It is perfectly defined but without optimization, it is less efficient than your first version. However, it is a premature optimization you need to identify that it is not optimized before preferring a code that is more complex to understand.

Your first coding version has code duplication. In the second version, you communicate clearly to fellow programmers that this is a default Foo and you reset to one.

See how without optimization your first version is more efficient and requires fewer assembly instructions [here](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAJykrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCBmAKykAA6oCoRODB7evgGp6ZkCoeFRLLHxSbaY9o4CQgRMxAQ5Pn6BdpgOWQ1NBCWRMXEJyQqNza15HeP9YYPlw0kAlLaoXsTI7BzmAMxhyN5YANQmO25OY8SYrKfYJhoAgvcPB0wKCkcAYqioXM8mAHYrI8jqCjmECODTsCHikvNFaHhkCBnmCvj8uBAlkcQOCIJIzNjAVYAQARaGosEAN1QeHQRyuSgIWJOQMpaNBACoCAg8B9TqTWSTyTsYWjAeTHhKKVLZS8DO90agzP82SCwRCoaLnnCEUiUerQd9lSzcXh8YShdLtYajjS6QzMEyWcT2Ry8CcdoKCTKHuKyaqRTDnpqWEwwi61X6wcauEcqH8bdGjT8zPGVUm3QmAHSMzDMpa%2BtFUMy5p35rG%2B6VyjgrWicRK8PwcLSkVCcNzWaxHBRrDaYE5mHY8UgETS1lYAaxAkh22a4/mHiQBiQXADYNBoABzJescSRN8dtzi8BQgDSj8crOCwGCIFCoFgpOhxciUNBPl/xV5GLibi9YFSSKYAAangmAAO4APIpIwnAjjQtAEHEZ4QNER7RGETQAJ7wbwmHMMQ2FQdE2hdGO3C8B%2BbCCFBDC0LhLa8Fg0ReMAbhiLQZ6UaQWBhkY4hMbxeBXN0VJOkemCqF0XjIXh5CCDUR6ItExA4R4WDyQQxB4CweErFQBjAAoYGQTBcE8fwggiGI7BSDIgiKCo6hCboZj6IYxhdpY%2Bh4NEZ6QCsqApHUDDcQAtGM6ACqYljWGYraoOJxA6VgAVYtUtRZC4DDuJ4bR6CEcxlBUehpBkoWTH4XAFBVWQDCVww1Z03T1DMVV6C1oW9M0DVDPEzXtfleSDX0fULANKy9usmwSHWDaHkJ7YcEcqhbmu4VrpIRw/sARx/tmGiHUcEC4IQJCDsOSy8BRWjXkgawEHCBBvhAmD4EQqV6FZwiiOIf4OfIShqEebmkBBakpPp%2BgLaQzaJZwUGyc9RyoFQq3rZt227ftR14ydHifvQxCXYSN1XisCDXFg8QZXuB6kHpQ7ZrOAKSP4HOc1za5w0ey2nnot21qQN73h%2Bz7E694tfiAwB/jsvGYEBmymdBsHNghdDIcQqHoUJBE4fJBtESRZEOPJ1GMAQdEMUeLFsRxtBcfJfGeYJrb4KJjjidxrZSTJck8RCSlCSpalERpWwjtpunQ4ZTDGar5ka7wP02f90g/U5IOuSACsGEYKDeTYKnpUFIVZBFUUxcXCW8ElcSpRJgWZeR2VvblHU1UVpT9WVhSVcN1W1UUDDjaVzU1G3bV9F3retQwPWzL3E2dUNuTD2MY3FX3XBTX2s17zDHCNrzS2cBjG1bUcwDIMguPZjsJ1nZ9l17%2BTTH3SAj3Pa973nV9Gqac/p2QvFnYGLlWy6AVhDJgUNKLzRPotBGHAkZPVkqjdGa0r7bVvvfA6T8ICEwlnES6OxrqXk/pTamww6acAZnpAEa5syJDXGYdmXNOFnxQQLC8QslhThAKw7MW4NBri3ASSQoidgcy4LuTgOxkH1xPJQu6iCzBKOPBwD%2BajSDJQyM4SQQA%3D). However, it is being optimized even with minimal optimization -O1 for instance. So I wouldn't be worried about it unless proven otherwise by a relevant benchmark.

If proven that code is inefficient, you can do this with minimal code duplication and a coding pattern that would be safer (less bug prone):

```
class Foo 
{       
    int m1 = m1_reset();
    int m2 = m2_reset();
    
    constexpr void internal_reset() { 
        m1 = m1_reset();
        m2 = m2_reset();
    }
    
    constexpr int m1_reset() { return 42; }
    constexpr int m2_reset() { return 84; }

public:
    constexpr Foo() = default;
    
    void reset() {
        internal_reset();
    }
};
```

- with C++20 use consteval instead of consexpr, though it should not make a difference in the generated machine code.

Comment: Thank for the informations. But I don't see how the last example would be scalable. 
What if there is more than one member?

Comment: Added option for multiple member reset

Comment: Your proposal requires member types to be default-constructible, and causes redundant member default-constructor calls in the class constructor.

Comment: True. The code is now fixed.

Comment: Thank you for taking feedback into account!

However your last example now recreates my original problem since you duplicate the member assignments in the constructor and in the reset function. This is what I meant by "not scalable" in my last comment :)

In addition, m1_reset could not both be marked as a consteval and used in reset if reset is not consteval.

Comment: Also 'constexpr Foo() {}' should be marked as '=default' to make it trivial

Comment: Yes exactly, that is why I would prefer the code operator=(Foo{}) unless demonstrated by a benchmark that you need something like this which requires code duplication.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is perfectly legal.

In some cases `= {}` may not work (e.g. if the default constructor is `explicit`, maybe in some other cases), but `= Foo{}` will always work.

> Given that it involves creating and copying an object, could it be less efficient to do it this way (without optimization)?

Maybe it's slightly less efficient, but don't concern yourself with premature optimization, unless you're absolutely certain this is going to be a performance-critical part of yoru code.

> Would you consider this a good practice to avoid duplication? Or is there another, more consensual way of proceeding?

Yes, avoiding duplication is a good thing. I'm not aware of a better way of doing this.